# How to remove items from external observableArray with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

### The goal

Remove items from external observableArray using KnockoutJS.

### The problem

There is two `observableArray` in my application. One for available products to buy and other to products that I have added in the Summary by clicking in `add button`.

Until here, all works fine. But now I need to remove items from Summary and change the button state/style — and I do not know how to access an external `observableArray` to do this.

To understand my problem, check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MThyv/5/) or see the markup in the next topic.

As you could see, when I click on `add button`, the product goes to Summary. When I click on remove — regardless if the button is from the summary or the product — I want to change the button state and remove the item from summary. Technically speaking, I want to remove the item from `items' observableArray` utilizing the `products' observableArray`.

### My code

HTML:

```
<ul class="summary">
    <!-- ko foreach: Summary.items -->
        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini remove-item">
            <i class="icon-remove">×</i>
        </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<h1>What would you to buy?</h1>

<ul class="products">
    <!-- ko foreach: Product.products -->
    <li>
        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
        <p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
        <!-- ko if:isAdded -->
        <button data-bind="if: isAdded" class="btn btn-small btn-success action remove">
            <i data-bind="click: $root.Summary.remove" class="icon-ok">Remove</i>
        </button>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:isAdded -->
        <form data-bind="submit: function() { $root.Summary.add($data); }">
            <button data-bind="ifnot: isAdded" class="btn btn-small action add">
                <i class="icon-plus">Add</i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Product(id, name, desc) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.desc = ko.observable(desc);
    self.isAdded = ko.observable(false);
}

function Item(id, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
}

function SummaryViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.add = function (item) {
        self.items.push(new Item(item.id(), item.name()));

        console.log(item);

        item.isAdded(true);
    };

    self.remove = function (item) {
        item.isAdded(false);
    };
};

function ProductViewModel(products) {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray(products);
};

var products = [
    new Product(1, "GTA V", "by Rockstar"), 
    new Product(2, "Watch_Dogs", "by Ubisoft")
];

ViewModel = {
    Summary: new SummaryViewModel(),
    Product: new ProductViewModel(products)
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Comment: Please add some usable snippets from your code to your question just in case your jsfiddle link goes dead in the future and this question becomes unreadable.

Comment: Thanks about your hint, Neal. I did it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [search for it](http://jsfiddle.net/Jr3Tk/).

You can query the cart for an item with the same id, and remove it

```
self.remove = function (item) {
    var inItems = self.items().filter(function(elem){
        return elem.id() === item.id(); // find the item with the same id
    })[0];
    self.items.remove(inItems);
    item.isAdded(false);
};
```

Unless you have hundreds of thousands of items, that should be perfectly fast enough. Just remember to use `items.remove()` so it'll know to update the `observableArray` :)

Comment: Oh, thanks Benjamin. But and if I click on the "x" at the item of Summary?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge You didn't add an action to it :) You should add a handler to it using the same technique in the answer. I'd probably do handle the design a bit differently though - have a single observableArray of products and two _computed_ functions for choosing which to show where. That way you don't need to manage this explicitly, you only need to set `isAdded` and it'd work which makes the most sense logically.

Comment: Benjamin, can you give me more details about *"two computed functions for choosing which to show where"*? Or, maybe an example? Your point of view is nice and will be a pleasure to hear it.

Comment: Gladly, but that's answering a different question and it's not really how StackOverflow comments work :) If you ask another question about modeling the data (that is, storing users and filtering) and maybe link it to this one - I'll gladly take a look :)

Comment: I will create another topic, Benjamin. I need to make my application as more consistent possible. Thanks about your help by now.

Comment: Benjamin, I have "unaccepted" the answer because I need to click on the "x" at the item of Summary and change the button state. [In this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jr3Tk/2/) I added the binding to the remove button of summary. Can you take a look, please?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge StackOverflow is not a "write this code for me for free" site. While I love answering questions about design, and how to structure your code, or about how to accomplish general things - like your original question which was about how to find the item in another collection in KnockoutJS I have no intention to solve application bugs that are not the question nor do I intend to write your production code. This is not how this site works, this will teach other users facing the same issue _nothing_ and is generally a bad approach pedagogically.

Comment: Moreover, I _have_ written a working version of it before I left my first comment to your question about the 'x' and it works. Follow the suggestion of adding an action of it, think about what needs an update and I know it'll work just fine.

Comment: Benjamin, I voted up your comment because you're right. I know about the objective of StackOverflow — I really really know, seriously, but the problem that I commented was something a little different: I do not know the concept. I need to enter in `Product` object with the Summary and change its property but I do not know how — neither the concept, nor the syntax. I'm not asking you about free code and sorry if that's what it seemed.

Comment: By the way, I turn your answer as accepted again. You resolved my problem, Benjamin. Thanks!

Comment: @Benjamin, Can you please explain why item.isAdded() has to be set to false?
My Array works just fine without it.

Comment: @Sarcastic because that's what OP's code does. His items have a `hisAdded` property. You are correct in your assertion that it is not required for the removal logic.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've declared products as an observableArray, you should just be able to call remove on it (according to [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)).  Given you have a reference to the object being deleted to pass in.